# Icon inside hidden Form in UI Bootstrap Popover causes other icon to be pushed down vertically

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a uib-popover which contains options for people to make donations. There are two icons in the popover - one for paypal, and one for patreon.

When a user clicks on the icon a new page is opened on the paypal/patreon page.

The issue arises, because the paypal icon is really a hidden form that is used to generate the html page. This hidden form causes the patreon icon to be shifted down about 10px, and not be parallel to the paypal icon like normal.

Here is the html for the popover template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="donatePopoverTemplate.html">
  <div><!--

  --><form class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="K2D7T7AWDFWT8">
      <input type="image" class="donate-svg" src="paypal.svg" border="0" name="submit">
    </form><!--

    --><img class="donate-svg" src="patreon.svg">

    <span style="display:inline-block; width:2px;"></span>
    <span class="popover-close popover-close-icon" ng-click="donate()" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

  </div>
</script>
```

I have created a plnkr to show exactly what is happening:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ojSmXkNBWOa0UmFWj10b

Anybody know how to keep the two icons on the same line? I have tried making the patreon icon position relative and shift it up a few pixels, but this still leaves the popover looking too high for the elements it contains.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by just putting the image inside the popover and also creating a hidden form. We then use an ng-click() to then submit the form.

Here is the hidden form:

```
<form id="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="{{paypal_id}}">
</form>
```

And this is what the template script looks like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="donatePopoverTemplate.html">
  <div><!--

    --><img class="share-svg opacity80" style="width:24px;" src="/images/logos/donate/paypal.svg"
      uib-tooltip="Paypal" tooltip-placement="top" ng-click="donate('paypal')"><!--

    --><img class="share-svg patreon-svg opacity80" style="width:23px;" src="/images/logos/donate/patreon.svg"
      uib-tooltip="Patreon" tooltip-placement="top" ng-click="donate('patreon')">

    <span style="display:inline-block; width:2px;"></span>
    <span class="popover-close popover-close-icon" ng-click="closeDonatePopover()" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

  </div>
</script>
```

Inside the ng-click we submit the form like this:

```
document.getElementById('paypal-form').submit();
```

A little hacky, but how and ever...

Answer (score -1):

You can use relative positioning and change the top on patreon.svg only.

```
element.style {
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
}
```

Comment: hi daniel - that leaves the popover looking too high - like I said, I tried that already..